# python key in dict.keys() performance for large dictionaries

Tags: python

I was wondering if you guys might be able to give me some advice in regards to making the performance of my code much better.

I have a set of for loops which look to see if a key is in a dictionary of which its values are a list, if the key exists, it appends to the list and if it doesnt it adds a new list in for that key

```
dict={}
for value in value_list:
   if value.key in dict.keys():
      temp_list = dict[value.key]
      temp_list.append(value.val)
      dict[value.key] = temp_list
   else:
      dict[value.key] = [value.val]
```

Now this code works fine, but evenrually as the dictionary starts to fill up the line value.key in dict.keys() becomes more and more cumbersome.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Just two small notes: 1) `... in dict.keys():` can be shortened to `... in dict:`. 2) Variables shouldn't be named after built-ins - in this case, consider renaming `dict`.

Comment: what do you mean by better way? simpler or faster?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
value.key in dict.keys()
```

That--in Python 2, at least--creates a list containing every key.  That gets more and more expensive as the dictionary gets larger, and performs an O(n) search on the list to find the key, which defeats the purpose of using a dict.

Instead, just do:

```
value.key in dict
```

which doesn't create a temporary list, and does a hash table lookup for the key rather than a linear search.

`setdefault`, as mentioned elsewhere, is the cleaner way to do this, but it's very important to understand the above.

Comment: Thanks for all your fast responses, appreciate all your help

Comment: That's some real info. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Using [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), this can be simplified to

```
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for value in value_list:
    d[value.key].append(value.val)
```

Comment: does that make the code run faster or just a simpler(shorter) way of writing the same thing?

Comment: @Saher: It's definitely faster than the original version, which used `dict.keys()` in each iteration, extracting a growing list of keys each time.  It's probably a bit slower than [sberry2A's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730993/python-key-in-dict-keys-performance-for-large-dictionaries/4731022#4731022), but not by too much.

Comment: `setdefault` is better than `defaultdict` most of the time.  It doesn't generally make sense to change the class itself when all you want to do is change a particular operation.  Only use `defaultdict` if you really *always* want this behavior.

Comment: @Glenn: I don't think it's possible to decide what is "better most of the time".  I would use a `defaultdict` rather as an idiom than for its functionality (which can always be easily simulated).  And by the way, I like your answer most :)

Answer (score 4):

```
your_dict.setdefault(value.key, []).append(value.val)
```

Answer (score 4):

Step 1: we transform the code using the temp_list into a single expression (I assume `temp_list` isn't needed outside this code), by using addition instead of the `append` method. Also, we don't need to use `dict.keys()` explicitly, as others mentioned (and in fact it wastes a huge amount of time).

```
for value in value_list:
   if value.key in dict:
      dict[value.key] = dict[value.key] + [value.val]
   else:
      dict[value.key] = [value.val]
```

Step 2: Transform the assignments-to-the-same-location by using the conditional expression syntax.

```
for value in value_list:
   dict[value.key] = dict[value.key] + [value.val] if value.key in dict else [value.val]
```

Step 3: Appending or prepending an empty list has no effect on the value of a list, so we can insert that, and then factor out the common 'addition' of the value.

```
for value in value_list:
   dict[value.key] = (dict[value.key] if value.key in dict else []) + [value.val]
```

Step 4: Recognize that the dict has built-in functionality for providing a 'default' value when the key is absent:

```
for value in value_list:
   dict[value.key] = dict.get(value.key, []) + [value.val]
```

Step 5: Instead of getting a value, modifying it and setting it back, we can use `.setdefault` to give us the current contents (or set them up if not already there), and then switch back to using `.append` to modify the list:

```
for value in value_list:
   dict.setdefault(value.key, []).append(value.val)
```

(I mean... I could have just looked at it and thought for a bit and arrived at this, but seeing each step makes it clearer where we're going...)

Answer (score 2):

```
if value.key in dict.keys():
```

Is very expensive because you're converting to a list of keys and then searching the list.  Just replacing that with:

```
if value.key in dict:
```

Should shorten the search to ~log N (EDIT: I stand corrected by **Glenn**, probably even faster because the Python dictionaries use a hash table).  Then simply:

```
dict[key].append(value.val)
```

Should speed things up a bit.  Using a temporary is not required and just eats some CPU cycles.

If you can give more details about what you're trying to do someone may be able to suggest a better algorithm.

Comment: dict lookups aren't O(log n).  They're a hash table, not a tree.

Comment: @Glenn: Been doing too many std::map's :-) I think there's a shortage of people asking questions with so many people rushing to answer every question... :-)