# Keep a list to prevent duplicates efficiency in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm having some trouble with a csv datasource which contains some duplicate IDs. The final result however should only have the ID once. Therefore it was decided that we should only take the first instance we see and ignore any other instances.

Currently my code is abit like this:

```
id_list = list()
for item in datasource: 
    if item[0] not in id_list:
        #process
        id_list.append(item[0])
```

The problem is that when the list grows, performance drops. I'm wondering if there are more efficient ways of tracking the already processed IDs?

Answer (score 5):

Use a `set` object, sets are guaranteed to not have duplicates and provide fast membership testing. You can use `set` like this

```
id_list = set()
for item in datasource: 
    if item[0] not in id_list:
        # process
        id_list.add(item[0])
```

This will be better, since the lookup in `set` objects will happen in [constant time](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set), as opposed to the [linear time lookup in lists](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#list).

Answer (score 1):

With reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4730993/2068635), I would suggest to use a dict.

Especially, the case of unique keys seems appropriate.

You could then try something like:

```
if key not in dict:
    [insert values in dict]
```

Comment: But the problem with this approach is, we cannot maintain the Order, as it is. We may have to use `OrderedDict`

Comment: I wasn't aware of the need for ordered results, because you already noted duplicate results...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a list you can use a binary search tree ordered by the ID.