# Python is 'key in dict' different/faster than 'key in dict.keys()'

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

Intuitively I think `key in dict` is faster than `key in dict.keys()` since `.keys()` creates a list of keys. This question is to confirm if this is true.

Just wondering if `key in dict` internally creates/uses a list to find if the key is present?

Also, is one method faster than the other?

Comment: `key in dict` work with hash.

Comment: Benchmarking the two approaches would provide a more definitive answer.

Comment: has answer here [python key in dict.keys() performance for large dictionaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730993/python-key-in-dict-keys-performance-for-large-dictionaries)

Comment: @ozgur yes thanks, although the question is not really a duplicate the answer there does answer this question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Short answer:**

- In python 2: your assumption is correct: `dict.keys()` slows down.
- In python 3: your assumption is not correct: `in dict.keys()` performs like like `in dict`

Details for py2 and py3 follow below.

**Python 2.7 answer:**

Your assumption is correct, for the following reasons:

- `dict.keys()` involves an additional function call (stack overhead).
- `dict.keys()` returns a list, which contains all keys in memory (as opposed to a lazy generator object). Hence it needs to allocate memory.
- `key in dict` can use a set object internally, which is an indexed lookup. `key in dict.keys()` is a linear search in a list

I created a small benckmark script to show my point:

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7

import datetime as dt
import random

dict_size = 1000000
num_iterations = 100

d = {i: i for i in xrange(dict_size)}

def f():
    k = random.randint(0,dict_size-1)
    return (k in d)

def g():
    k = random.randint(0,dict_size-1)
    return (k in d.keys())

def test(func):
    t = dt.datetime.utcnow()
    for i in xrange(num_iterations):
        func()
    print "%s --> %1.6f s" % (func, (dt.datetime.utcnow()-t).total_seconds())

test(f)
test(g)
```

Output (python 2.7.6 Ubuntu 14.04):

```
<function f at 0x7ff2e0126d70> --> 0.000598 s
<function g at 0x7ff2e0126de8> --> 5.191553 s
```

I also tested with the nr of iterations and the dict size swapped (dict of only 100 items, 1M iterations).

```
<function f at 0x7f94cb5e6d70> --> 3.614162 s
<function g at 0x7f94cb5e6de8> --> 7.007922 s
```

Here the results are much closer together.

So the performance difference really grows with the size of the dict.

**Python 3 answer:**

I adapted the script for python 3:

- `xrange` is gone, use `range` instead. (not in the performance-critical inner loop of the test function, so limited performance impact)
- use braces with `print`
- change shabang line to `#!/usr/bin/python3`

And tested with python 3.4.3 on the same machine.

- dict_size = 1000000; num_iterations = 100

  f --> 0.000590 s
  g --> 0.000565 s
- dict_size = 100; num_iterations = 1000000

  f --> 4.525487 s
  g --> 4.837232 s

So in python 3, the performance difference is gone.

Comment: Please note that, `dict.keys()` returns a set like view object in Python 3, not a list. And they don't waste memory too.

Comment: Also `dict.keys()` involves an attribute lookup. Note that in python3 `dict.keys()` returns a view instead so your second point is only partially correct in python3.

Comment: I think there theoretically should still be a difference although less, in python 3 you still have one attribute lookup and one function call - these do take time.

Comment: For reference, here’s the internal (Python 3) function that dispatches `if key in .keys()` to `if key in dict`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Objects/dictobject.c#L3369

Comment: Python3.9  f is faster than g.
12s to 17s on 10 million iterations on my machine.
So using .keys() should be discouraged as less pythonic and less performant. IMO