# json recursive comparison with another json in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.x

I am comparing if all elements of a json object are inside another json.
for that i grab all keys in one layer of the small one and check if they are in the big one and if they are the same. to go into a deeper layer i call the function giving it the element that contains the deeper layer. (in this funtion now i detect the deeper layer with the key "results" but i futur it will be changed to a variable key.
my Problem is that i can't call the recursive function. it sais "string indices must be integers, not unicode" in the script when trying to call the function in the function.

```
def compareJson(example_json_s, target_json_s): 
    #parsed_json
    example_json = example_json_s
    target_json = target_json_s
    p = 0
    keys = []
    for key in example_json.keys(): 
        keys.insert(p, key)
        p = p + 1

    passed = 0;
    for x in keys: 
        print "Keys"
        if x != "results": 
            if not x in target_json or x not in example_json.keys() and not example_json[x] == target_json[x]: 
                passed = 1
        else:
            print """###inhabits "results " going one layer deeper"""
        compareJson(example_json[key], target_json[key])
    return passed
```

and some example json objects:

```
{
    "results": {
        "clock": true,
        "update": false,
        "autoreg": false
    }
} 

{
    "id": "1523",
    "dlid": "009029",
    "serial": "1017030022",
    "statuscode": 128,
    "results": {
        "event": true,
        "counter": true,
        "clock": true,
        "eqep": true,
        "usb": false,
        "modem": true,
        "sim": true,
        "pin": true,
        "encrypt": false,
        "upload": true,
        "update": true,
        "autoreg": true
    },
    "ok": false,
    "confirmed": false
}
```

And the Error code here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/philip/Desktop/empfang_test.py", line 199, in <module>
    empfange() #Programm wartet in einer Endlosschleife auf eingehende Nachrichten.
  File "/home/philip/Desktop/empfang_test.py", line 193, in empfange
    checkvalue=compareJson(json.loads(config[1][1]),parsed_json_dummy)
  File "/home/philip/Desktop/empfang_test.py", line 183, in compareJson
    compareJson(example_json[key],target_json[key])   
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: Can you fix indentation and add the complete error message?

Comment: what is the desired output? True/False or a list (or dict) of which fields are present?

Comment: What about fixture https://pythonhosted.org/testfixtures/comparing.html that provide dict comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following code should do the trick:

```
def compareJson(example_json_s, target_json_s):
 example_json = json.loads(example_json_s)
 target_json = json.loads(target_json_s)
 return compareParsedJson(example_json, target_json)

def compareParsedJson(example_json, target_json):   
 for x in example_json:
   if type(example_json[x]) is not dict:
     if not x in target_json or not example_json[x] == target_json[x]:
       return False
   else:
     if x not in target_json or not compareParsedJson(example_json[x], target_json[x]):
      return False

 return True
```

In the first function we parse the full JSON object (including the recursive parts). The second analyses them.

I have made several changes to your code.

- There is no need to get a list of the keys first, you can just iterate over `example_json.keys()`. Additionally I would have replaced it with `keys.append(key)` in your example.
- The function checks if the type of the nested json object is now a `dict` (it has already been parsed). If not, then it compares them, if so, then it goed into the next one. You might want to add a similar clause for lists.
- The function returns `False` as soon as a part of the JSON is not the same.

EDIT: In response to your posted error code, I think you might not have parsed the json correctly. I took your comment `#parsed_json` to mean that you had, but I think you were missing the `json.loads` method calls I included in my code example above..?

Comment: You are most welcome. Thank you for the acceptance of the answer.

Comment: On a side note, avoid using `dict.keys()` when all you want is to iterate over a dictionary. Simply remove the `.keys()` to get `for k in dict:`. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730993/python-key-in-dict-keys-performance-for-large-dictionaries

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution

```
def contained(a, b):
    """ checks if dictionary a is fully contained in b """
    if not isinstance(a, dict):
        return a == b
    else:
        return all(contained(v, b.get(k)) for k, v in a.items())

print(contained(d1, d2))
```

which, for your input gives `False` and for

```
d1 = {
      "results": {
                  "clock": True,
                  "update": True,
                  "autoreg": True
                 }
     }
```

gives `True`

and for

```
d1 = {
    "results": {
        "clock": True,
        "update": True,
        "autoreg": True,
        "qqq": True
    }
}
```

i.e. a key is missing from the target (e.g. `qqq`), it gives `False`

Of course you can call it with

```
contained(json.loads(example_json_s), json.loads(target_json_s))
```

when starting from a JSON string

Comment: I think that if there is a `k` such that `k not in b` it should return `False`?

Comment: @MrHug yes, fixed. Thank you